# elmah download log is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, elmah.mvc

VS2013, MVC5, SQL error logging
elmah.corelibrary version 1.2.1 
elmah.mvc version 2.1.1

I successfully installed elmah into an MVC5 site using the SQL database logging mechanism.  The elmah logging works great on both the dev (local SQLExpress) and hosted site (hosted SQL Standard).  Everything works as expected such as the error reporting from the elmah page, RSS feeds, etc.

But the download log function never returns after being clicked.  So, several questions:

1) Is anybody familiar with the function failing for any particular common reasons?
2) Where is the best place to report problems with elmah?

Thanks.

Best Regards,
Alan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was pinged as a result of someone up-voting this post.  With the passage of time there is more to add.  It's not that the answer above is incorrect; if those are the versions being used, the information above is correct.

However, in the time since this post was made elmah.mvc version 2.1.2 became available in the NuGet Package Manager.

This new version works properly and the package installs very nicely.  Thought those looking at this problem should know.

Comment: Using elmah.mvc 2.1.2 and still have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out there was a problem with elmah.mvc relating to the download log function.  It is documented in the issues listed at http://code.google.com/p/elmah/issues/list.  You have to do a search for 'all issues' (in the search drop down box), and search for 'download log'.  Issue 338 is at http://code.google.com/p/elmah/issues/detail?id=338&can=1&q=download%20log&colspec=ID.  In that issue Atif Aziz (the author of elmah) lists 4 different work arounds.

I chose to fall back to the basic elmah package and the download log problem disappeared.  You'll have to follow the recommended security practices which are different that what elmah.mvc provided, but it does work and the problem was in elmah.mvc.

Best Regards,
Alan